How can I determine if the Dope Sheet menu state is expanded or closed via Python?
Is there a way I can access certain UI elements through a script in Blender? I am trying to access information within the Dope Sheet Editor. One thing I would like to achieve is to determine if a menu is expanded or closed using Python.


